# Error sending email via microsoft exchange for Android : java.lang.NullPointerException: format == null

Tags: java, android, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Below is my code I am using to send mail using EWS for Android.

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("user","pass");
        service.setCredentials(credentials);    
        service.setUrl(new URI("https://valid_server/ews/Exchange.asmx"));  


        EmailMessage msg= new EmailMessage(service);
        msg.setSubject("Hello world!");
        msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Sent using the EWS Java API."));
        msg.getToRecipients().add("myemail");
        msg.send();
```

However it is not working and I am getting the below error. Can anybody please tell me about this.

```
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕      java.lang.NullPointerException: format == null
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1799)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1777)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.getEwsHttpWebResponse(ServiceRequestBase.java:936)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:821)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:46)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:143)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.internalCreateItems(ExchangeService.java:463)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.createItem(ExchangeService.java:534)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Item.internalCreate(Item.java:215)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage.internalSend(EmailMessage.java:125)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage.send(EmailMessage.java:253)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at com.example.test.MainActivity$EWSOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:61)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at com.example.test.MainActivity$EWSOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:39)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
 02-12 03:26:00.411  18432-18457/com.example.test W/System.err﹕ at       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Can you make sure to check if setting the sender information by calling `msg.setFrom()` helps in this case ?

Comment: @vk239, I am still getting the same error :(  EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress();
                emailAddress.setAddress("MYEMAIL");
                msg.setFrom(emailAddress);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862635/jwebservices-with-android-doesnt-work